# Generate dialog box during onmouseover event in lightning components

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am building a lightning component where I want to generate a small dialog box, whenever we hover over a link. Please see screenshot attached.

The green portion should be generated on "onmouseover" event, whenever you hover over the red one (link). I have gone through the documentation but I haven't found any topic related to the same.

Thanks in advance..!!
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [lightning:overlayLibrary](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_lightning_overlayLibrary.htm) documentation. That includes an example of a popover that:

> Popovers display contextual information on a reference element and
>   don’t interrupt like modals. A popover can be displayed when you hover
>   over or click the reference element. Pressing the Escape key closes
>   the popover. The default positioning of the popover is on the right of
>   the reference element.

Comment: I did see this and have used this before for a different purpose. Never paid attention that it can also support "onmouseover" event. Thanks for pointing it out @Keith C. I will try this.